# Disable fullscreen in ipad vimeo

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo

Is it possible to disable the video playing on fullscreen?
When I press play on the player on the iOS, it is playing the video in fullscreen mode, whereas in android it is playing in the normal mode.

Sharing the code I'm using

```
        <div>
        <iframe 
        src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/120061340?playsline=true" 
        frameborder="0" 
        allowfullscreen="false"
        allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
        webkit-playsinline="true" 
        playsline="true"
        playsinline="true"
        style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" 
        controlsList="nofullscreen"
        title="Sample Video">
        </iframe>
        </div>
        <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js">
        </script>
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something here

Answer (score 0):

You're loading an `iframe` and trying to put `video` element attributes on it. Instead of loading the `iframe`, you'd need to call the video file directly in your own `video` element. Alternately, you can add a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) that waits for the Vimeo video element to be inserted into the page and which then adds the `webkit-playsinline` attribute to it.

Comment: I'm using the code in a webview inside React Native application, If I change it to the suggested method, will it still have the Vimeo controls? can you please share a code snippet for me to checkout this?

Comment: If you pull in the video file directly, no, you will not have the Vimeo player. Adding a sample mutation observer above.

Comment: Never mind, Vimeo uses CORS to block frame manipulation so you can't actually do it without using a proxy.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, the controls I mentioned is documented in the vimeo player js github - https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/
I still haven't heard back from them